# How to use icons instead of img in select form?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select, styling

I have to create dropdown list with select form. I want to use a FontAwesome icons: "fa-angle-down" (when list is not selected) and "fa-angle-up" next to first list item (when list is expanded). How can I do that? Do I have to use JavaScript or jQuery?

```
<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>numbers</legend>
        <select name="numbers">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
        </select>
     </fieldset>
</body>
```

Comment: What kind of code do you have so far? Post a code snippet

Comment: In its current form, your question is unclear. What are you calling *select form*? A `<select>` html element? Also please note you're supposed to show some code and we're supposed to show you how to change it to get the result you want. See [ask] page on ways to improve your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, I mean html <select>

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for forcing the browser to use a custom CSS for your select case with the custom styling for the drop-down list.

You need to first wrap a select element with the span and then add your select field for which we will be adding before and after pseudo classes.

in before pseudo-class, we will add a background color for the toggle button of the select area and in after pseudo-class, we will add the angle icon using the fontawesome glyph.

```css
.selectwrap {
  position:relative;
}
.selectwrap::before {
        content:'';
        right:1px;
        top:-8px;
        width:30px;
        height:38px;
        background:#ffffff;
        position:absolute;
        pointer-events:none;
        display:block;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .selectwrap::after {
        content:"\f106";
        font-family: "FontAwesome";
        font-size: 12px;
        right: 12px;
        top:3px;
        color: #c4d3dc;
        padding:0 0 2px;
        position:absolute;
        pointer-events:none;
    }
    .selectwrap:focus::after {
        content: "\f107";
    }
    .selectwrap select {
        padding:7px 15px;
        height: 40px;
        margin: 0;
        background: #eff3f5;
        border:1px solid #e4ebef;
        outline:none;
        display: inline-block;
        -webkit-appearance:none;
        -moz-appearance:none;
        cursor:pointer;
        width: 300px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span class="selectwrap">
<select>
<option selected="'selected'" value="0">Sunday</option><option value="1">Monday</option>
<option value="2">Tuesday</option>
<option value="3">Wednesday</option>
<option value="4">Thursday</option>
<option value="5">Friday</option>
<option value="6">Saturday</option>
</select>
</span>
```

Hope my answer helps you out.